# Upload text as file with POST (multipart/form-data) using php and wget

Tags: php, bash, curl, multipartform-data, wget

I'm using PHP + wget to upload a file on an old cgi-bin control panel web-to-fax.

The cgi (dont know its language) checks the file format (doc txt pdf) and then returns me the error: "incorrect file format". If I do it manually everything works fine.

The form is 6 steps long, every step is quite similar (it asks you for destination, number of retries, etc) and my PHP + wget scripts work as expected (cookies handling, post, get, etc).

This is how the form looks like (lightened and translated from the original):

```
<FORM ACTION="xyz_httpfileupload" METHOD="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
Write the file with full path:

    <INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="sourcefile" size=40 maxlength=200>
    <input type=hidden name=destfile value="N527yb">
    <!-- this is a random generated filename -->

    <input type=hidden name=urlredirect value="./xyz_upload?destfile=N527yb&filename=/tmp/VOTU9.txt">
    <!-- this is another random generated filename -->

    <input type=submit name="Upload" value="Upload">
</FORM>
```

The code (and some tests) shows that you can use both GET or POST.

This is my code, followed by explainations:

```
$command =  ' wget --debug -qSO- --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies '.
            ' --save-cookies='.$cookie.' --load-cookies='.$cookie.
            ' --header="Content-Type:text/plain" '.
            ' --post-file="'.$file.'" '.
//          ' --post-data="sourcefile='.$rawfile.'" '.
            ' --post-data="'.
                'destfile='.$randfile.
                '&urlredirect=xyz_delivery?destfile='.$randfile.
                '&filename=/tmp/'.$randname.'.txt" '.
                '&pload=Upload "xyz_httpfileupload" ';
$data = shell_exec($command." && sleep 10 2>&1 | tee ".$dir."logfile.txt");
```

$cookie is the full server path to the cookie file. It works as expected.

$file is the full server path to my file. It's a simple file.txt

$randfile and $randname are retrieved using preg_match on the HTML output.

The commented line with $rawfile is a try to send the raw urlencoded content instead of the file: somebody say it's a working alternative but not for me, or at least I didn't code it right.

I also tried to post directly into the URL you see in urlredirect, but I get the same error file format incorrect, but I can't assure the right parsing from the cgi if I jump a step.

In any case logfile.txt was left empty.

I know curl would make my life easier, but the ubuntu platform the script resides on only supports wget and I feel I'm half the way on.

Advice me on methods to debug it. I can't via shell because I would lose the random names generated on every refresh. Perhaps TCPdump? Thanks for any advice you can give me, I think this is the ultimate discussion to definitely solve this matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post request with Wget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699666/post-request-with-wget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After years and pains, I concluded that CURL is the way. This is my code snippet that works so far (BASH) to send files:

```
formname="data=@"$HOME/samplefile.txt
$(curl -X POST -F $formname "http://www.mywebsite.com/form.php")
```

And a clever solution (PHP) to get those files without actually using any , which it's also good for security:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["data"]["tmp_name"];
$name = "final_folder/".$_FILES['data']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$name);
```

Cheers!