# POST request with Wget?

Tags: linux, post, wget

I want to use Wget to upload a picture to a server's `test` folder using an authentication token, `AUTH_1624582364932749DFHDD`.

This command doesn't work, I get an "authorization failed" error:

```
wget --post-file=nature.jpg http://ipadress:8080/v1/AUTH_test/test/ --post-data="AUTH_1624582364932749DFHDD"
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Wget does not support sending "multipart/form-data" data. `--post-file` is not for transmitting files as form attachments, it expects data in this form: `key=value&otherkey=example`. It is actually possible to POST other formats (like JSON) if you send the corresponding header.

`--post-data` and `--post-file` work the same way: the only difference is that `--post-data` allows you to specify the data in the command line, while `--post-file` allows you to specify the path of the file that contains the data to send.

Here's the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):

> ```
> --post-data=string
> --post-file=file
> ```
>
> Use POST as the method for all HTTP requests and send the specified data in the request body. `--post-data` sends *string* as data, whereas `--post-file` sends the contents of *file*. Other than that, they work in exactly the same way. In particular, they *both* expect content of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, with percent-encoding for special characters; the only difference is that one expects its content as a command-line parameter and the other accepts its content from a file. In particular, `--post-file` is *not* for transmitting files as form attachments: those must appear as `key=value` data (with appropriate percent-coding) just like everything else. Wget does not currently support `multipart/form-data` for transmitting POST data; only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Only one of `--post-data` and `--post-file` should be specified.

Regarding your authentication token, it should either be provided in the header, in the path of the URL, or in the data itself. This must be indicated somewhere in the documentation of the service you use. In a POST request, as in a GET request, you must specify the data using keys and values. This way the server will be able to receive multiple pieces of information with specific names. It's similar with variables.

Hence, you can't just send a magic token to the server, you also need to specify the name of the key. If the key is "token", then it should be `token=YOUR_TOKEN`.

```
wget --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' http://example.com/auth.php
```

Also, you should consider using [curl](https://curl.se/docs/manual.html) if you can because it is easier to [send files using it](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F).

Comment: How can i send my auth token in this case ?

Comment: If it were a basic html form, how would you name the input that contains the token? Because that should be: token=AUTH_1624582364932749DFHDD

Comment: I was going to say it @Hasturkun :D

Comment: No, it's not an HTML form, i want to upload the picture "nature.jpg" on a server, this server require a token 'AUTH_*******' to identify the user, so i've to send the file and the token (string) with the POST request

Comment: @Hasturkun: i use 'curl' for few time, but it didn't work for me....i mean i don't know how to use it :)

Comment: @Maxime: ah i haven't seen the edit, thank's :) so in my case i will use : 'X-Auth-Token = *******' and 'Photo = nature.jpg' right ?   Ps : X-Auth-Token is the name of the variable

Comment: @Dady: Sending file content as form data is unsupported by wget: *Wget does not currently support "multipart/form-data" for transmitting POST data*

Comment: That won't work. It's not that simple to upload files. You should try with curl for that.

Comment: @Maxime yes i mean with curl, such : curl -d "X-Auth-Token=AUTH_tk8c1eecae98e845159cebf69f06bb10f2" "Photo=nature.jpg "http://ipadress:8080/v1/AUTH_test/test/" !! (but l've always authorization failed)

Comment: You should try to put the token in the header: curl -H "X-Auth-Token:AUTH_tk8c1eecae98e845159cebf69f06bb10f2" ...

Comment: Finaly it works : curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tk8c1eecae98e845159cebf69f06bb10f2' http://ipadress:8080/v1/AUTH_test/test -T nature.jpg