# wget textarea with characters in name

Tags: forms, curl, textarea, wget

I have a form with a textarea which i want to fill using wget. This is the text area i am concerned with

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="100" name="/home/site/admin/browse/exec.done"></textarea>
```

when i try using wget with this, nothing gets picked up. Any ideas? I am trying this and have tried multiple options but none seem to work

```
wget --http-user=admin --http-password=admin http://example.com --post-data="/home/site/admin/browse/exec.done"="checked"
```

Comment: When exactly should the textarea be filled, on page load? Or is there some other process after the page loads that should fill it?

Answer (score 0):

The `post-data` option should be properly quoted and contain urlencoded data, i.e.,

```
--post-data="%2Fhome%2Fsite%2Fadmin%2Fbrowse%2Fexec.done=checked"
```

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699666/post-request-with-wget).